# OpenGl - Evaluators and Normals

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to use evaluators to create a plane:

```
void Plane::draw(float texS, float texT)
{
    float div = v.at(0);

    GLfloat ctrlpoints[4][3] = {
        {-0.5, 0.0, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.0 ,-0.5}, 
        {0.5, 0.0, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.0, -0.5}};

    GLfloat texturepoints[4][2] = {
        {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0/texT}, 
        {1.0/texS, 0.0}, {1.0/texS, 1.0/texT}};

    glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, 0.0, 1.0, 3, 2, 0.0, 1.0, 2 * 3, 2, &ctrlpoints[0][0]);
    glMap2f(GL_MAP2_TEXTURE_COORD_2, 0.0, 1.0, 2, 2, 0.0, 1.0, 2 * 2, 2, &texturepoints[0][0]);

    glEnable(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3);
    glEnable(GL_MAP2_TEXTURE_COORD_2);

    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);

    glMapGrid2f(div, 0.0, 1.0, div, 0.0, 1.0);
    glEvalMesh2(GL_FILL,0, div, 0, div);  
}
```

It displays the plane correctly, it gives me a 50*50 grid, for example, and the texture I apply to it is also displayed properly. However, if I try to apply a golden appearance to it, it just gives me a dull brown color.

I know I can get what I want by creating a rectangle with with quad or triangle strip, but the point here is to use evaluators.

One answer I found said that evaluators calculate normals automatically with the enabling of GL_AUTO_NORMAL, and that that was the only necessary instruction. But even then, the author of the question couldn't do what he wanted.

And I do have GL_NORMALIZE enabled in the initialization.

Comment: Note: Evaluators are depreciated functionality and aren't present in OpenGL 3.1+. Please reconsider using triangle strips instead.

Comment: I prefer using strips myself, but the point of part of the project is to learn about evaluators. I have this using quad strips and triangle strips, but alas.